# Сравнение версий Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide

Объясните популярно, чем отличается Delphi 7 от Delphi 9, 2010, 2011?

Answer (score 5):

- переделанная IDE (кому то нравится, кому то нет).
- расширенный синтаксис языка (перегрузка операторов, шаблоны, методы у record'ов, юникод, x64 (у последних версий делфи) и многое другое)
- всякие .NET
- новые баги (а как же без них)

Answer (score 5):

В более новых версиях Delphi добавлены новые компоненты (некоторые морально устаревшие компоненты и библиотеки удалены (например компоненты `QReport`)), новые свойства для старых компонентов, и, конечно же, поэтому размер бинарника будет больше. Например, в Delphi 7 пустая форма весит 345 Кб, а в Delphi XE - 895 Кб. Конечно же, в более новых версиях есть дополнения к языку, автозаполнение (пишешь `Begin`, уже вставляет `End` (после нажатия `Enter`)). Шаблоны некоторых проектов незначительно изменены (по крайней мере изменён шаблон консольного приложения в Delphi XE). Всего не перечислить, но подробнее про каждую из версий, можно узнать на [этом сайте](http://delphilab.ru/) - можно на [этой](http://www.delphilab.ru/content/blogcategory/53/96/)
странице.

Недавно откомпилил в Delphi XE 2 пустой проект - от 6,75 метров весит! А с помощью FireMonkey  - ещё больше!..

Comment: Дался вам этот размер бинарников, как будто по прежнему на дискетах все носим ;-)

Answer (score 4):

После Delphi 2009 это был ужас.
Но после 2010 мне лично очень нравится.
Основные отличия от 7:

1. Поддержка `unicode`.
2. Компоненты `Ribbon` (как меню в 2007 офисе).
3. Значительно улучшена работа с памятью (утечек при крупных проектах намного меньше).
4. Классы для работы с `touch screen`.

В серии ХЕ добавлены компоненты для работы с облачными серверами.
В ХЕ2 возможность компиляции под MAC OS и x64.

Много еще чего разного, все не перечислить.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 9 нет))

- В Delphi 2009+ -- поддержка **unicode**
- XE+(версия 2011 - это XE) -- **Gestures**
     и Touch Screen
- 2009+ RibbonControls, поддержка png, 
     встроенный редактор ресурсов и т.д. и 
     т.п.
- 2009+ **Улучшенный отладчик**

Изменений масса))